# Move text in span to the next line only partially

Tags: html, css, text, line, word-wrap

Is it possible to move text in span to the next line only partially?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TWbWx/174/) is the fiddle. If you will resize the width of the output window the text `HHHHH...` will move to the next line at some point, while it would be enough to just move a few characters to the next line. And the problem is that moving the whole text part to the next line leaves a lot of blank space.

[image]
[image]

html:

```
<div class="box">
       <span>Text </span> 
       <span>HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH</span>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.box {
    background-color:#00FF7F;
    height: auto;
    width:100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;    
}
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: Even if you applied `word-wrap` to the spans instead of the parent div, the behavior does not change (at least by my test in a Chromium-based browser.) My guess - not explicitly possible; it might simply create to many catch 22-situations for the browser if they had to handle it that “dynamic”. Depending on the _actual_ use case(?), perhaps something like automatic hyphenation could serve you better.

Comment: @Viira, I want ot avoid **blank space**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.box span{white-space: pre-wrap;
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;
    white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap;
    white-space: -pre-wrap;
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;}
```

```html
<div class="box">
       <span>Text </span> 
       <span>HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Oh. Very perfect. Thank you.